# .NET Core 3.1 - Entity Framework - Embedded objects

Tags: entity-framework-core

I can store my .NET models in SQL db as long as they are **simple objects**

but what about **embedded objects, their ID's and relationship between tables** ?

if we consider such a model :

```
public class ClassA
{
 int Id,
 string name,
 ClassB data
}
```

- do I deal with the subclass ClassB storing/loading from SQL myself ? or does EF deal with these scenarios ?
- do I need to define relationships between my classes on the SQL level ?
- does the MVC framework convert these objects automatically to typescript equivalents ? (for Angular apps)

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about Relationships in EF. You should be keeping your objects seperate, keeping the data in a relational structure when using Sql. Some reading can be found here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#:~:text=Relationships%20in%20EF,-In%20relational%20databases&text=In%20Entity%20Framework%2C%20an%20entity,two%20entities%20in%20that%20relationship.

If you were using a data store like Azure's Cosmos DB, you could embed child objects. Embedding child objects isn't how to handle relational data and as SQL is meant to be a relational data store, its not intended to store embedded objects. With that being said Sql Server 2012 and newer do have a Json column that you can try adding to schema. I have not looked at how EF handles the Json column that sql has.

Comment: quiet sad, I thought EF would deal with this, I'll have a look at your link, thanks